# YII MaskedTextField does not work after ajax-loading

Tags: ajax, yii, textfield

I have:

View - `_form.php`:

```
echo CHtml::ajaxLink(CHtml::image('/images/plus.png', ''),
    $url = CController::createUrl('User/Dynamicreference'), $ajaxOptions=array (
       'type'=>'POST',      
       'success'=>'function(data){  $(body).append(data);}'
    )
);
```

And `UserController.php`

```
public function actionDynamicreference(){
    $this->widget('CMaskedTextField', array(
       'name' => 'Items[items_reference][]',
       'value' => '',
       'mask' => '999999',
    ));
}
```

Mask input does not work after ajax-loading (jQuery doesn't executed after the AJAX request). How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is in fourth parameter processOutput of CController.renderPartial(). Set it to true and you'll get jquery.maskedinput plugin on your ajax requests.

// action

```
// ...
if (Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest)
    {
        $content = $this->renderPartial('content', null, true, true);
        echo $content;
        Yii::app()->end();
    }
// ...
```

// view file content.php

```
<?php $this->widget('CMaskedTextField', array('mask'=>'99:99:99','name'=>'someName')); ?>
```